The bar stacking chart does not show numbers less than 10% during in SuperSet
The bar stacking chart does not show numbers less than 10% during in SuperSet
Do anybody know how to fix this moment?
look at screenshot:
enter image description here
Yes, but I don’t understood wheare i can fix it.
Pleas help.
